# How to intervene CreateUSerWizard, memebership provider to add User.Identity.Name to Users table

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, identity

I am using the ASP.NET application service; Membership to manage sign-up and login for users in website.

So after calling: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers

I Added a Login control and CreateUSerWizard control; each in a separate aspx page.

The Provider creates the necessary tables in the database (Users, Roles, Applications, ...)

The **Users** table has this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [UserId]           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [UserName]         NVARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    [IsAnonymous]      BIT              NOT NULL,
    [LastActivityDate] DATETIME         NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [User_Application] FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Applications] ([ApplicationId])
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_UserName]
    ON [dbo].[Users]([UserName] ASC);
```

I am planning to add a column - named **UserIdentity** - that will hold the value of the `User.Identity.Name` for the signed-up users.
By default signed-up users are logged in automatically.

`[UserIdentity]    nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,`

I want to list user names from this table and make something special for the name that belongs to the current logged in user. So I can retrieve **UserIdentity** and check if it matches the current user `User.Identity.Name`

**The Question is:** How to add `User.Identity.Name` to the **UserIdentity** column. I am using the default CreateUSerWizard control. Is there a way to intervene and make this Add.